# Choice of plural or singular form in the structure of "nouns of nouns of nouns ... "

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

I have come across this sentence:

> WE, the Heads of State/Government of Member States of the Association
> of Southeast Asian Nations (ASEAN), namely, ...

from this [link](https://asean2019.go.th/en/news/bangkok-declaration-on-combating-marine-debris-in-asean-region/)

I am wondering why "state/government" is singular. Ain't there 10 governments in total? so could you please help me to understand the choice?

Comment: Each Head is the head of only one state!

Comment: I know one head for one state, but I just don't know when to see things as an individual and when to see things as a group. For instance, from the start, "heads", we see it from a collective perspective, then "government/state", singular, we see it from an individual perspective, then the following "member states", "Association" and "nations", then we jump to the collective perspective again... I am so confused!

Comment: "Head of state/government" is a fixed phrase. Its plural form is "heads of state/government".

Comment: The preposition "of" often licenses an uncountable sense for ordinarily countable nouns.  For example, we rarely encounter "for *an* example" despite how countable examples typically are.

Answer (score 2):

'Head of State' is a fixed phrase. Its plural is 'Heads of State'.  France has a Head of State. Germany has a Head of State. They are the Heads of State of those nations.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Actually, I am still not convinced why the plural form should be 'Heads of State' not 'Heads of States'. Actually, I have been confused for a long time! Five years ago I asked a similar question, see the link below. I think 'Heads of States' could also mean the collection of the individual heads of each state in an association (similar to the first answer in the link)  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340558/the-plural-of-noun-of-noun-three-types-of-combination